# Scalate SSP fails on certain if blocks

Tags: scala, scalate, ssp

Consider the following dummy SSP file:

```
#{
    val testMap1 =  Map("a" -> true, "b" -> true, "c" -> true)
    val testMap2 =  Map("d" -> false, "e" -> false, "f" -> true)

    val something = true
    val value = 3
}#

<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

#if(something)
    <h1>True</h1>
#elseif(value > 2)
    <h1>False, but higher</h1>
#else
    <h1>False</h1>
#end


#if(testMap1.forall(_._2) && testMap2.forall(_._2))
    <h1>All true</h1>
#elseif(testMap1.forall(_._2) || testMap2.forall(_._2))
    <h1>One map true</h1>
#else
    <h1>Neither</h1>
#end
```

which is rendered by the following:

```
import java.io.File
import org.fusesource.scalate.{ TemplateSource, TemplateEngine }

val engine = new TemplateEngine()
val file = new File("path/to/file.ssp")

engine.layout(TemplateSource.fromFile(file))
```

This will fail.

The first if block will nicely execute, but the second if block will fail with some SyntaxError (`Missing if at...` or `Cannot have more than one else at ...`). I don't see any syntax difference between the two blocks. I'm bumping into this problem each time I generate booleans "on the fly" with some functional stuff. Am I not allowed to do this?

For instance, if I change the second block to the following, it **does** work:

```
#{
    val testMap1true = testMap1.forall(_._2)
    val testMap2true = testMap2.forall(_._2)        
}#

#if(testMap1true && testMap2true)
    <h1>All true</h1>
#elseif(testMap1true || testMap2true))
    <h1>One map true</h1>
#else
    <h1>Neither</h1>
#end
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Just ran into the same thing. Do you remember if you figured out what the issue was?